# Use function outside method declaration

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have a function `get_user_agent()`:

```
def get_user_agent():
    valid_user_agents = []
    db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='password',db='garbagedb')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        with db.cursor() as cursor:
            useragent_query = "SELECT `ua` FROM `useragent`"
            cursor.execute(useragent_query)
            useragent_value = cursor.fetchall()
            valid_user_agents.append(useragent_value)
        db.close()
    except:
        print("error SELECTing useragent_value")
    return valid_user_agents     

db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='password',db='garbagedb')
cursor = db.cursor()

get_user_agent() # function invoked
```

Then to try to use the `list` `valid_user_agents` - This **does not** work:

```
for ua in valid_user_agents:
    print("do something?")
```

But then I cant use in a `for` loop, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't save the return value.

Comment: "This does not work" is not a problem specification.  Show your full MCVE and the full error message, including stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **user2357112** pointed out first, you ignored the return value.  **valid_user_agents** is a local variable to your function, and is undefined in the main program.

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
for ua in get_user_agent():
    print ("Do something?")
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it hits the except

Comment: I don't think I can help any more until you provide the requested code and symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value,

```
>>> def foobar():
...     foo = 1
...     return foo
... 
>>> bar = foobar()
>>> if bar:
...     print('foobar')
... 
foobar
>>>
```